# $amount is not showing when executing PigLatin DUMP command

Tags: apache-pig

Here is a partial data set in my input file called `transactions.csv` in HDFS with 6 fields (columns)
as following:

TransactionID, Date, CustomerID, $Amount, Category, Product

```
00000000,11/03/2016,4001992,$699.37,Computers,Mother Board
00000002,03/31/2013,4007301,$65.52,Automotive,Headlight
00000006,05/11/2019,4004244,$83.68,Tools,Screw Driver
00000010,07/14/2014,4001082,$14.22,Home,Table Cloth White
00000017,11/23/2017,4003326,$164.69,Home,Outdoor Chair
```

I'm using the following PigLatin Command to load the file with a defined schema

```
txn = LOAD '/user/pig/input/retail/transactions.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS
(
txnid:chararray, 
date:chararray, 
custid:chararray, 
amount:double, 
category:chararray,
product:chararray,
);
```

The following command is used to display the output on the screen

```
DUMP txn;
```

Here is the generated output

```
00000000,11/03/2016,4001992,,Computers,Mother Board
00000002,03/31/2013,4007301,,Automotive,Headlight
00000006,05/11/2019,4004244,,Tools,Screw Driver
00000010,07/14/2014,4001082,,Home,Table Cloth White
00000017,11/23/2017,4003326,,Home,Outdoor Chair
```

Somehow the $amount field which is defined as double data type in the schema is not displaying and showing `,,`

What will be the reason that $amount field is not shown?

Answer (score 0):

Your data also has a $ in the column $Amount and you are trying to load that into a double datatype field. This will not work.
A workaround is to load that column to a chararray field, replace the $ sign and cast it to double.

```
txn = LOAD '/user/pig/input/retail/transactions.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS
(
txnid:chararray, 
date:chararray, 
custid:chararray, 
amount:chararray, 
category:chararray,
product:chararray -- Remove comma
);

txn_amt = foreach txn generate txnid,date,custid,(double)(replace(amount,'\\\$','')),category,product;
```